# Can i install wordpress only on sub-domain

Tags: php, wordpress, subdomain

i have a website coded in php running on a domain. I want to install wordpress only on a sub-domain for blogging purpose. Can it be done? if yes, please guide me. I have tried searching for it but found nothing. please help

Comment: please somebody answer it.

Comment: yes, you can certainly install in a subdomain using cpanel. see the explanation here: 
https://www.eukhost.com/kb/how-to-install-wordpress-on-a-subdomain-using-cpanel/

Answer (score 2):

the general answer is yes. but you must answer this question:

- what is your control panel (ex: the DirectAdmin, the CPanel, or etc)?

if you have a control panel so, you must search about this issue on the control panel forum.

if NOT, you must follow these steps (it's a general solution. therefore, for getting a specific answer give me more details. such as,  what is your web server? what is your DNS server?)

1- create a directory on the public directory of the server and install Wordpress on it (ex: path-to-the-public-directory/subdomain-directory)

2- create an A record on the DNS server to resolve subdomain.domain.com

3- create an appropriate config for your web server to handle requests of your subdomain

Answer (score 2):

Yes this can be achieved.

1. Create your sub-domain by logging into your web host account.
2. Navigate to your sub-domain root folder using an FTP client such as Filezilla
3. Follow the instructions here: https://wordpress.org/support/article/how-to-install-wordpress/#basic-instructions